# Can I format my HD from running Linux system?

Tags: linux, format, wipe

I have a Debian Linux PC which I would like to have the HD completely wiped.

Is it possible to do this while running Linux, without having to insert a removable media and boot it?
The HD to be format is the same Linux is running at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can issue a "full erase" command to the disk, *and* you can just overwrite the disk through `/dev` regardless of its partitions being still mounted – people even do this by mistake; I've seen many cases of someone accidentally writing an .iso to their system disk instead of a USB stick.

Though while the filesystem is mounted, the OS might still write new data back to the HDD, e.g. after the superblock has been wiped the OS might end up writing it back. Also, the OS might crash due to trying to *read* filesystem structures that have already been erased from disk.

So for a *full* overwrite, you'd need to make some preparations, to reduce the OS background activity as much as possible. Ideally the only running process should be your root shell, nothing else that would cause the OS to read or write data.

1. To achieve this, boot Linux in rescue mode – or if that's not possible, log in through text console or SSH, then shut down the GUI if it is running (stop the 'gdm' or 'lightdm' service). Also shut down any other services, especially those which would write data to disk (syslog, systemd-journald, httpd).
2. Then unmount unnecessary partitions (like /home) and use `mount -o remount,ro` to remount the `/` filesystem read-only, or if that doesn't work, `fsfreeze` to pause any further writes it.
3. Finally begin the erase. As mentioned before, at this point you *could* just overwrite the entire block device via /dev, but I would instead recommend using `hdparm` to issue an "ATA Secure Erase" command, which tells the disk to fully erase itself. This has only minor advantages for standard HDDs, but becomes much more important for SSDs as well as SMR HDDs, as it is able to erase even 'reallocated' locations that the OS cannot access.

   Note: For SATA SSDs prefer "ATA *Enhanced* Secure Erase" (for HDDs it doesn't matter). For NVMe disks, instead use the "Sanitize" command through `nvme-cli`. For SAS disks, `sg_sanitize` should be equivalent.
4. When hdparm returns (1-2 hours later for HDDs, a few seconds for SSDs), just physically power off the machine. (You might be able to cause a poweroff via /proc/sysrq-trigger. The regular shutdown command won't work because you just erased it.)

<sup>(The exact hdparm commands have been deliberately left out.)</sup>